# Apache - How can I redirect a directory request to other port on same server?

Tags: apache, redirect

I would like whenever the user navigates to "http://myserver.net/plex" to be redirected to "http://myserver.net:32400/web/" - which is my plex server. (or whatever myserver.net's ip is - so that if i accessed it via it's local ip, it would be redirected to "http://mylocalip:32400/web/").

From what i've seen it involves something about VirtualHosts? But I don't have anything like that in my httpd.conf so I don't know where to start.

Comment: Are there any `.conf` files in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` ?

Comment: in /etc/httpd/conf/conf.d/ I have 4 files, none of which contain a <VirtualHosts> declaration. Charset, localised-error-pages,other-vhosts-access-log & security.

Comment: At the moment, does `http://myserver.net:32400/web/` open fine in user's browser? And what happens if user types `http://myserver.net/plex`?

Comment: Yes it does, and if I visit /plex, I just get an Object not found error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. Didn't need to mess about with VirtualHosts, I just put @Dusan Bajic's below two commands in my httpd.conf and it worked fine:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/plex(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}:32400/web$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Create file named `myserver.net.conf` in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` with this content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myserver.net

  ErrorLog    logs/myserver.net-error_log
  CustomLog   logs/myserver.net-access_log common

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/plex(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}:32400/web$1 [R=301]

</VirtualHost>
```

Also, in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` find the line :

```
#NameVirtualHost *:80
```

and uncomment it, then restart httpd service.

Comment: I don't have that #NameVirtualHost line (Either commented or uncommented) in my httpd.conf file at all, should I add it? Also, I don't want the redirect to occur whenever the user accesses myserver.net, id like to to occur whatever name (local ip, global ip, hostname) the server is accessed from.

Comment: It's not working though. Also apache is telling me that "NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release" for that line in httpd.conf.